# Accessing Local storage in Selenium on Powershell

Tags: powershell, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, local-storage

I am using powershell to run selenium using the chrome driver.
I want to retrieve a LocalStorage item's value by it's key `"access.keyhttps://api.specialcomapny.com"`.
When I use `window.localStorage` in the chrome browser fired by Selenium, I can view that these values exists.

I tried the following code.

```
$ChromeOptions = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeOptions
$ChromeDriver = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver($ChromeOptions)
$ChromeDriver.WebStorage.LocalStorage.GetItem("access.keyhttps://api.specialcomapny.com")
```

The value is however coming as null. And when I debug the script, it says, "error retrieving property webstorage". And the $HasWebStorage property within the `$chromeDriver` is read as `$false`.

Is there any missing reference?
When I was going through I saw this medium article:
https://medium.com/@jonashavers/accessing-sessionstorage-and-localstorage-with-selenium-remotewebdriver-f3935d8d7d9b

I couldn't find a similar one for the powershell situation.

So the question is:

How can we access the local storage item using a key when running selenium on chrome driver using powershell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well since I couldn't figure it out using native selenium command to fetch local storage variable, I executed the javascript code `window.localStorage.getItem()` inside the browser console using selenium using the selenium `.ExecuteScript()` method for chrome to get the value of the local storage key, and then saved the output inside the script.
The code is as follows:

```
 $AccessToken = $ChromeDriver.ExecuteScript("return window.localStorage.getItem('access.keyhttps://api.specialcomapny.com')");
```